# Volume icon missing after removing (and re-installing) pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

I reinstalled PulseAdio beacause I my indicator-sound just disappeared, but it didn't help.

[image]

Strangely, I have installed indicator-sound and still don't have that sound control. Nay, I don't even have any settings in "Sound Settings":

[image]

I ran "Volume Control PulseAudio" from unity launcher and I got this:

[image]

So I ran **start-pulseaudio-x11**:

```
$ start-pulseaudio-x11 
Connection failed: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

What Can I do to fix it?

Comment: I posted my problem in this thread too: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871144

Comment: if you reset your pulseaudio conf via `mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse_backup` , logout and login does your audio stuff reset correctly?

Comment: Oh my god! It fix my problem! THANK YOU fossfreedom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

Some pulse-audio issues can be resolved by resetting your pulseaudio configuration file then logging out and logging in to regenerate it automatically.

```
mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse_backup
```

From your comment - this is exactly the case for your situation :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in the login screen, I could change the volume but it was a session issue.

I typed:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/$USER
```

and restarted. Now I have the control.